# SQL query dynamic table name in FOR

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table **tbl1** which has a column **tbl_names**. This column contains the name of some other tables.
Now I want to write a query in the following format:
`select * from (select tbl_names from tbl1)`

I know that the query above will not work but how I can achieve this? Do I need to write a stored procedure or something like that and loop on each value of second query and execute first query?

Thanks

Comment: stored procedure can help you

Comment: Thanks Arun for quick reply. But sorry to say that I'm not familiar with stored procedures at all so can you please help me with this :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use prepared statements

```
SET @a = (select tbl_names from tbl1);
SET @x := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @a);
Prepare stmt FROM @x;
Execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some dynamic SQL. Build up a SQL string with the query that you want to execute and then call `exec(@sql)`

Full example:

```
declare cur cursor for
select tbl_names from tbl1

declare @sql varchar(100), @tbl varchar(100)

open cur

fetch cur into @tbl

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    set @sql = 'select * from ' + @tbl
    exec(@sql)
    fetch cur into @tbl
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a pseudonim to the subquery:

```
select * from (select tbl_names from tbl1) a;
```

Good luck )

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in mariadb, have you verified that it works in mysql?  It doesn't seem like it would.