# How to update rows of the tables whose name match a format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a db which has multiple tables out of which few have table names like STD*. All of the tables STD* have columns named userTag. 
So

1. first I would like to list all the tables of that db whose name match STD*
2. and then update the userTag of every row to "on call"

for item 1 I can use 
[Get all table names of a particular database by SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913620/get-all-table-names-of-a-particular-database-by-sql-query)
but how can i combine its result with item 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table `TABLES` on `information_schema` to match names, but you won't be able to use them in a single query.  You could write a stored procedure to do this though:
[SQL query dynamic table name in FOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510490/sql-query-dynamic-table-name-in-for)

Comment: Can you provide the stored proc here?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla take a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99298/how-do-i-perform-a-query-on-a-dynamic-list-of-tables

Answer (score 0):

> 1. first I would like to list all the tables of that db whose name match
>      STD*

You can find all the table name using the query below.

```
use databasename --replace this with your db name
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name like 'STD%'
```

> 2. and then update the userTag of every row to "on call"

To update values of column named `userTag` to `on call` in the `STD*` tables. You can generate a dynamic script like this:

```
use databasename --replace this with your db name
select 'UPDATE ' + table_schema + '.' + table_name 
        + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''on call'';'
from information_schema.columns
where table_name like 'STD%'
and column_name = 'usertag';
```

Comment: I dont want to do that one by one on tables

Comment: @WaterfrVilla So you are telling me that you can't copy and paste the output from the select statement and run it?

Comment: the output of part 1 is a set of tables, i dont want to cop/paste their name onto second part one by one. I want the whole thing in a single script or stored proc

Comment: @WaterfrVilla That's the beauty of the second part, you don't need to copy and paste the table name, it's generating all that for you dynamically.