# Sql loop through Database tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have 20 tables.

One of the table is named "Connections" contains two columns "TableName" and "NextHi"

```
+--------+-------------+
| NextHi | TableName   |
+--------+-------------+
| 43     | Page        |
+--------+-------------+
| 32     | User        |
+--------+-------------+
```

So in the column "TableName" are names of other tables.

Each other Table has Column "Id"

What I need is Script which will loop trough all tables in database and fore ach table return one row with 3 Column:

1. TableName
2. MaxID - of the table
3. NextHi value from "Connections" table for current Table

So result should be like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| TableName | NextHi      | MaxId |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| Page      | 43          | 435   |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| User      | 32          | 768   |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

I have script which returns me this, but it has Select for each Table, and table names are hard coded:

```
(
  SELECT
    "User" as `TableName`,
    `Connections`.`NextHi`,
    (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `User`) as `MaxId`
  FROM `Connections`
  WHERE `Connections`.`TableName` = "User"
)
 UNION ALL (
  SELECT
    "Page" as `TableName`,
    `Connections`.`NextHi`,
    (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Page`) as `MaxId`
   FROM `Connections`
  WHERE `Connections`.`TableName` = "Page"
)
```

But I need this in loop as one Select

EDIT:

Correction: It doesn't really need to be just one Select, but it should be simpler then what I have now

Comment: So you table Connections contains a list of all your DB tables?

Comment: Yes it contains a list of all my DB tables. Also in that list there are one or two additional table names which doesn't exit int my DB. But if that is big deal we can ignore it, I can remove them.

Comment: I don't think this is doable in one Select as you need to use prepared statements: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510490/sql-query-dynamic-table-name-in-for

Comment: Would it help to be able to read mysql's own metadata? 
e.g. 
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema= 'yourdb'

Answer (score 2):

```
select NextHi, TableName, auto_increment from information_schema.tables,
Connections where table_schema='databaseName' and table_name=TableName;
```

Edit: After posting this I see that @BryanT had already commented with this while I was testing.

Comment: *auto_increment* would of course only work if `ID` column of all the mentioned tables have auto_increment enabled.

Comment: auto_inrement is not enabled for ID of these tables. I need Max(ID)

Answer (score 0):

You need a feature called "dynamic SQL", which isn't supported well in MySQL, but [it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure).

You need to write a query which yields a valid SQL statement as a result by querying `Connections`, and then execute that statement.